# Fix Subquery returning more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I know there have already been many questions regarding this but i can't seem to figure out a logic to solve my problem.Here is my script, please let me know if you require more information.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT StationID
from
    station
        JOIN
    cars ON station.StationID = cars.CurrentStationID
WHERE
    station.Capacity = (SELECT 
            Count(cars.CurrentSlotID)
        FROM
             cars Group By CurrentStationID
        );
```

What i am trying to do is ,

I have a table called Station with a Capacity value which is INT.

I have another table called cars, which has StationID foreign key.

Now i want to get all stations which are full based on the Capacity of station database  equal to the count of cars in car database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should show each station, its capacity, and the number of cars at the station, only where the station is full OR over its capacity. (hence the >= rather than = in the HAVING clause)

```
select s.stationid,
       s.capacity,
       count(c.currentstationid) as num_cars_at_station
  from station s
  join cars c
    on s.stationid = c.currentstationid
 group by s.stationid, s.capacity
having count(c.currentstationid) >= s.capacity
```

Comment: @Brian. Thanks this works as expected, a +1 for considering over capacity !!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.StationID
from station s
JOIN cars c ON s.StationID = c.CurrentStationID
group by s.stationID, s.Capacity
having count(c.CurrentStationID) = s.Capacity
```

Comment: why group by capacity ?

Comment: @ôkio: Because I use it in the having clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more of a SQL Server person, but this sounds like what you need:

```
SELECT 
    StationID
from
    station
WHERE
    station.Capacity = (SELECT 
        Count(CurrentSlotID)
    FROM
         cars 
    WHERE cars.CurrentStationID = station.StationID
    );
```

You need to indicate that you want to count only those records from `cars` that have the same `CurrentStationID` as the station you're joining to in the main query.  And you don't actually need `cars` in the main query, since you don't access any data from it there:  just `station`.  And therefore you don't need DISTINCT, since you'll only be returning one record per `StationID` value.  (Assuming `StationID` is the primary key of `station`.)

Comment: Thanks this works as expected as well as the others. Your explanation is great. I will wait to make the answer with most votes.Thank You :)

Comment: Hi, back again. From your defined query, how may i be able to tweak and know Empty Stations ?

Comment: @beginningperl  You would replace the outer query WHERE clause with this:  `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT CurrentSlotID FROM cars WHERE cars.CurrentStationID = station.StationID)`.  There are other ways to get the same effect, but this is a fast-performing one.